# The incrementer values for an array using a size_t operator

Tags: arrays, c, pre-increment, size-t

### In the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void main ()
{
    int n[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    
    printf("%s%13s\n","element","value");
    for (size_t i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
           printf("%7d%13u\n", i, n[i]);
        }
    
}
```

the output is:

```
element        value
  0            1
  1            2
  2            3
  3            4
  4            5
```

What I don't understand is how `i` which is pre-incremented, gives off the values from 0 to 4.

I believe it should be 1 to 4, since it would not pass the condition.

What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: the third part of the `for` loop statement (the iteration expression) is always executed *after* an iteration finishes

Comment: And it should be `int main(void)` to be correct, usually with a `return 0;`.

Comment: @UnholySheep I used your comment in last part of my answer, when I realised while typing, that I 'd get very close to saying the same. Hope you do not mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter `i` is only pre-incremented inside `++i;` in the third part of the loop definition. That is a complete statement in which pre or post increment is irrelevant.
The observable behaviour of `i` is unrelated to the increment, because all output is done in the separate body of the loop.

As Unholy sheep mentions in a comment:

> the third part of the for loop statement (the iteration expression) is always executed *after*  an iteration finishes

Answer (score 1):

To further illuminate the comment's and the other answer's point that

> the third part of the for loop statement (the iteration expression) is always executed **after** an iteration finishes

the manual unrolling of that loop would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void main ()
{
    int n[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    
    printf("%s%13s\n","element","value");
    size_t i = 0;
    printf("%7d%13u\n", i, n[i]);
    ++i;
    printf("%7d%13u\n", i, n[i]);
    ++i;
    printf("%7d%13u\n", i, n[i]);
    ++i;
    printf("%7d%13u\n", i, n[i]);
    ++i;
    printf("%7d%13u\n", i, n[i]);
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Please fix my misquote (broken markdown) of Unholy Sheep comment. Otherwise nice visualisation, making together a nice answer with mine.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is how i which is pre-incremented

It isn't, `i` and `n[i]` are totally independent in that `printf` loop.

- `i` still increases from 0 to 4
- `n[i]` then has corresponding values from 1 to 5. The index `i` is still in range [0,4].

By the way, you should use `%zu` for `size_t` type.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    printf("%7zu%13d\n", i, n[i]);
}
```

Comment: about `%zu`, this code snippet is from the book **C how to program**, and they used `%u`, can you calrify on why to use `%zu` instead?

Comment: `%u` is for unsigned type, `%zu` is for `size_t` spefically